# Ontario Electrical Code - Can AFCI outlet be used in the beginning of a branch circuit instead of AFCI breaker?

Tags: electrical

I'm building my basement. Can I use an AFCI outlet at the beginning of the circuit instead of AFCI breaker? Which branch circuits need AFCI and which do not?

- One dedicated circuit for bathroom (outlet/light/fan)
- One dedicated 20A circuit for kitchen
- Two general purpose circuits (hallway, bedroom outlets and lights))

Comment: I don't know for Ontario, but NEC permits this if the wiring from the breaker to the outlet is in metallic conduit (perhaps also if it's MC Cable, but I'm not sure about that.)

Comment: What if there is an arc on the line side of the AFCI outlet? What prevents someone from adding a junction before the AFCI outlet?

Comment: Above Ecnerwal's answer is the correct way to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus an arc on the line side will be dealt with by the metal shielding, is the concept.

Comment: Where does the metal shielding come from?